# Vim not using variable value when changing a setting

Tags: vimscript, neovim, variables, set

I have the following vimscript:

```
let g:base_path="~/.config/nvim/"
let g:plugins_path=base_path."plugins/"
let g:repos_path=plugins_path."repos/github.com/"

set runtimepath+=g:repos_path."Shougo/dein.vim"
```

But it's doing something weird, instead of seeing a path at the end, I'm seeing this:

```
runtimepath=~/.config/nvim,/etc/xdg/nvim,~/.local/share/nvim/site,/usr/local/share/nvim/site,/usr/share/nvim/site,/usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvi
    m/runtime,/usr/share/nvim/site/after,/usr/local/share/nvim/site/after,~/.local/share/nvim/site/after,/etc/xdg/nvim/after,~/.config/nvim/after,g:repos_path.
```

It's adding this to the end:

```
,g:repos_path.
```

instead of

```
,~/.config/nvim/plugins/repos/github.com/Shougo/dein.vim
```

Why is vim not adding the path to the end correctly and also why is this happening?

EDIT:
The only way to get this to work is to use the fullpath without any quotes like this:

```
set runtimepath+=~/.config/nvim/plugins/repos/github.com/Shougo/dein.vim
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5736810/3536548):

> let &backupdir=s:vimetc.'backups/'

I realised what I needed to do was this:

```
let &runtimepath=&runtimepath.','.g:repos_path."Shougo/dein.vim"
```

I have to say, vim script can be a bit inconsistent, using bare strings works fine but without it you need to some some weird stuff to get it to work if you want to use variables.

Comment: There is no inconsistency, `set`ting an option and `let`ting a variable are very different things.  vim offers an interface to options as variables, by prepending `&`.   `let &runtimepath.=','.g:repos_path.'Shougo/dein.vim'` would also have worked.